# When I converted the Keras Model to TFLite Model, then the input shape changed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I want use Classification on mobile environment, so converted Keras Model to TFlite model.
and I made a random value on Android studio using JAVA and put it on. but original (desktop) input was (4, 1, 300, 3) = [(1,300,3), (1,300,3), (1,300,3), (1,300,3)].. after convert, input (1, 300, 3).. I don't know why it is.

In the original local environment, I saw an array of the form (4, 1, 300, 3) as input and a tensor of the form [1, 7] as output.

However, in the Android environment, the input is (1,300,3) and the output is [1, 7].

The model is a Multi CNN and receives a total of 4 inputs.

Please Feel free to send me any comments!